# Method to update a TableModel

Tags: java, sql

This is a method that I use to search for individual records in a database. It's in a class called Model:

```
    public ArrayList<Person> getPerson(String fName, String sName){
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    String findSql = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE f_name = ? AND s_name = ?";

    if(con != null){
        try(
            PreparedStatement findStatement = con.prepareStatement(findSql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ){
            findStatement.setString(1, fName);
            findStatement.setString(2, sName);

            ResultSet rs = findStatement.executeQuery();

            rs.beforeFirst();
            while(rs.next()){
                String title = rs.getNString("title");
                String name = rs.getNString("f_name");
                String surname = rs.getNString("s_name");
                String address1 = rs.getNString("address1");
                String address2 = rs.getNString("address2");
                String address3 = rs.getNString("address3");
                String postcode = rs.getNString("postcode");
                String empStatus = rs.getNString("emp_status");
                String searchStatus = rs.getNString("search_status");
                Person p = new Person(title, name, surname, address1, address2, address3, postcode, empStatus, searchStatus);

                people.add(p);
            }

            rs.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return people;
}
```

I've a class called CandidateTable that needs a TableModel. I kind of want to use the above to update the data in the table. Should I overload this method, change it to be able to use 'no' parameters (ie retreive every record using LIKE), or implement some other solution?
Thanks!

*edit: sorry for the significant changes - I'm trying to make the post more clear.

Comment: If you intend to use the result from the above method to update data then yes. I see no reason for trying to overload the above method. BTW, you should free both the ResultSet as well as the PreparedStatement (usually in a finally block as that guarantees they are freed even when there's an exception)

Comment: this method doesn't actually update data it just retreives an arraylist of people with a specific first name and surname from the database. the class that calls this method then displays these people in a JDialog.


RE the above question -i've just decided just to write another method to get all records from the database, then I can add and take away search parameters without worrying about additional logic and clarity.


thanks for the resource advice - ill put them in finally (although isn't the PreparedStatement ok in the try-with-resources block? i'm new to this)

Comment: The PreparedStatement should also be closed and it's best to put the resource deallocation code in the finally block. Retrieving all records is OK only for very small tables, otherwise you better implement some  search routines (including paging)

Comment: i thought try with resources closed the it? anyway, yeah, this is a relatively small table - i'm just trying to give a relatively 'real time' view of the database in a JTable next to the input area. i assume ill get to paging eventually XD

thanks for your help

Comment: Just been messing about with it and i realise why i've done it this way